# How to relocate my pets with me inside the EU?

Tags: rabbits, house-moving

I may go to Lithuania for about one year. Now I have to consider the subject of my two rabbits. Either I take them with me, or I search another person to care for them in this time. To make this decision I need more information.

(It would be a relocation inside the EU. They do not have documents yet.)

**What formal problems I have to solve, if I want to take my rabbits with me?**

Comment: I have found the laws for pet movement inside the EU: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32013R0576

Comment: @Allerleirauh it looks like you found the references, do you want to post an answer to your own question, to benefit others in the future?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I can, but I can not guarantee I would understand the wording of law correctly. So I am still searching for someone who have done a relevant relocation, or who understands the wording of law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now all is done, I could answer my question too:

The vet has given my both rabbits a chip for identification
The chip number and vaccinations are noted in their vaccination papers.

We moved via car from Germany through Poland to Lithuania, so we had no border controls. All airlines that were fitting us do not allow rabbits as hand luggage and our rabbits being transported in the luggage room was not an acceptable option for us.

Three rabbits are okay to pass borders in EU as pets with the owner. More have to have special allowance (for animal import/export).

Answer (score 2):

Rabbits are part of Annex I, Part B:

> ANNEX I
>
> Species of pet animals
>
> PART A
>
> Dogs (*Canis lupus familiaris*)
>
> Cats (*Felis silvestris catus*)
>
> Ferrets (*Mustela putorius furo*)
>
> PART B
>
> Invertebrates (except bees and bumble bees covered by Article 8 of Directive 92/65/EEC and molluscs and crustaceans referred to respectively in points (e)(ii) and (e)(iii) of Article 3(1) of Directive 2006/88/EC).
>
> Ornamental aquatic animals as defined in point (k) of Article 3 of Directive 2006/88/EC and excluded from the scope of that Directive by point (a) of Article 2(1) thereof.
>
> Amphibia
>
> Reptiles
>
> Birds: specimens of avian species other than those referred to in Article 2 of Directive 2009/158/EC.
>
> Mammals: rodents and rabbits other than those intended for food production and defined under ‘lagomorphs’ in Annex I to Regulation (EC) No 853/2004.

For them are these rules:

> SECTION 2
>
> Pet animals of the species listed in Part B of Annex I
>
> Article 9
>
> Conditions applicable to the non-commercial movement of pet animals of the species listed in Part B of Annex I
>
> 1. Insofar as the Commission has adopted a delegated act pursuant to Article 19(1) with regard to pet animals of one of the species listed in Part B of Annex I, the non-commercial movement of pet animals of that species into a Member State from another Member State shall be subject to compliance with the conditions laid down in paragraph 2 of this Article.
> 2. Pet animals of the species referred to in paragraph 1 may be moved into a Member State from another Member State only if they fulfil the following conditions:
>
> (a) they are marked or described according to the requirements adopted pursuant to Article 17(2);
>
> (b) they comply with any preventive health measures for diseases or infections other than rabies adopted pursuant to Article 19(1);
>
> (c) they are accompanied by an identification document duly completed and issued in accordance with Article 29.

[Source: eur-lex.europa.eu](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2013/576/oj).